# Opera (and Chrome) is changing colors of my images! Why ? How to stop that?

Tags: browser, png, opera, color-profile

[image]

link to this image : [img](https://github.com/nCdy/nCdy.org/raw/master/http/wp-content/themes/wp-platinum-live/images/menu1.jpg)

Firefox shows this image as is.

But if I open it with Opera Gray colors is different instead if I download it and open with any editor. Why ?

Here is how opera shows me my image : 
[image]

Here is true image colors :
[image]

More picture (Just wondering)

[image]
[image]

How to make my png shows native in all browsers. (as like as on FireFox or IE or Windows picture viewer)

Comment: You mean the blue circle on the left that has a blue background around it?

Comment: I mean gray colors for div "pagemenu" is different.

Comment: @Snicksie Not to be rude but that just made my day. You noticed that blue area _Behind_ the arrow that shows how the two greens are different color.

Comment: I saw the blue circle had a blue background too, but the nightly version didn't :) I didn't see a difference between the both green circles, thats why I got confused ;)

Comment: Chrome also displays the colors the same way as Opera does which would lead me to the conclusion that FF Nightly is the one doing it wrong.

Comment: Odd. IE9 actually displays the image's colors similar to FF Nightly. Comparing the images in Photoshop, the colors match if copied from IE9, but they don't if copied from Opera. Also, if downloading the image, then the colors are like they show up in FF Nightly and IE9, so both Chrome and Opera would be displaying it incorrectly. Possibly a gamma issue, like with PNG images in old IE?

Comment: so you can just open https://github.com/nCdy/nCdy.org/raw/master/http/wp-content/themes/wp-platinum-live/images/menu1.jpg and download it and open with any picture viewer. Opera Lies !

Comment: You are right, just edited the comment :)

Comment: Check I made glorious question update. It's png displaying trouble. Please check if chrome lies same as opera with colors .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to Photoshop, the image contains a embedded color profile "LG L245WP". This will natually make the colors different.  Opera (and presumably Chrome) doesn't support color profiles.  I recommend saving the image out with sRGB color profile, then it'll look the same in all browsers.

Comment: I'm just wondering even Windows Paint and Picture Preview on same system shows it different.

Comment: @Petter Nilsen : Hi, This worked well Thanks +voted up

Comment: All browsers but Firefox, which will just use the raw RGB values.

Comment: Just had the same issue with Chrome and [this image](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/light-oak-wooden-flooring-texture-background-top-view-smooth-brown-laminate-seamless-wood-floor-light-oak-wooden-flooring-174897743.jpg). My image editors all showed it with much warmer colors after download. Was able to fix it mucking with the color profiles (but also realized later that taking a screenshot would've been easier). Thanks.