# My whole website is different colors in Firefox and Opera

Tags: html, css, firefox, colors, opera

I'm making a website on if Cadbury's website redesign was given to me. It's going OK, but there are completely different colours displayed in Firefox than in Opera and other browsers.

My background color is : `#482e91`

Firefox:
[image: ScreenShot Firefox]

Opera:
[image: ScreenShot Opera]

I've also noticed this in other browsers. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According  this answer:[Opera (and Chrome) is changing colors of my images! Why ? How to stop that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510234/opera-and-chrome-is-changing-colors-of-my-images-why-how-to-stop-that) 
 
**Use:**

```
background-color:rgb(72,46,145)
```

I convert the color here:https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hex-to-rgb.html

Comment: tell me if it helps you

Comment: No didn't change a thing. Still different in the two browsers.